# Retain library references in VBA/Excel between startups

Tags: vba, excel

My problem seems very basic and I was surprised to not find an answer after searching. So I would like to keep my library references between startups of Excel but they seem to reset every time.

I am using dictionaries in my VBA code so I need Microsoft Scripting Runtime enabled. How do I keep this reference up? Or is there a way to force it through my VBA code? This would actually be the best solution as this tool is going to be used by a few other people in my organization.

Someone has a solution to this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx

Comment: That is a good resource but my problem is not as much missing references but keeping the references I have checked between startups.

Comment: I understand this, but it's worth checking if the references are as they're supposed to be, before examining other possible sources of the problem. Anyway, at the bottom of the first link I posted, you'll find an entire Debugging procedure for Excel startup errors, which might be causing this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/StartupErrors.aspx

Comment: References are workbook specific (as I told you on Mr Excel). If you always need the same references for all new workbooks (which would be weird, IMO) you need to use a template.

Comment: Another possibility is simply that the workbook in question has been corrupted. Have you tried copying the code into another workbook and setting the proper references in the new workbook?

Comment: You must have a public module in your xlsm file to maintain links. If you've written your code in sheet modules this would cause your symptoms

Comment: @Rory: do you have link to 'Mr Excel' ?

Comment: @SMeaden Yes, sorry: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1057789-saving-vba-references-between-startups.html

Comment: @Rory: thanks, I need to broaden my forum marketing ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am new to VBA so didn't quite know how these things work. Hope I can figure out how to make an easily usable template for my colleagues. So far running the old module as a personal (global) macro ran into some issues.

Comment: You don't even need a reference to use the scripting dictionary, if you use late binding.

Comment: I'm with @HarassedDad - Would declaring public variables work for you, or do you need to dynamically update your references while the workbook is open?

Comment: Can you confirm you do have a public module sheet? You don't need to have anything in it, but if you don't have one Excel will not keep your references.

Answer (score 1):

With this question you're essentially getting into the topic of early binding vs. late binding.

I'm assuming what you're doing now is early binding, which means you are adding the reference manually from the tool bar.

To persist the reference I'd suggest going with the late binding route.

Add the following lines to your code:

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

From there you can access the dict object by doing dict.method/function.

I'm providing you a few examples below that should help you get the idea of how to utilize this:

```
dict.add key, value
dict.remove key
dict.count
```

Given you're already working with the dictionary you probablly have a general understanding. If you need to understand more of the built in methods/functions refer to the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/x4k5wbx4(v%3dvs.84)